# Unity Android KitKat application stopped issue

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to get `Unity3d` project working on `Android` `KitKat` device. I installed `APK` on device and during launching got error:

> application stopped

Than I figured out that problem not in my project's code but in starting `Activity` which is generated by `Unity`. I've caught following `exception`:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.getFire.plugin/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerExсeption

To confirm that, I've created empty project from a scratch - but the error still occurs.
Here is screenshot of `Unity` empty project:

[image: Unity empty project settings]

Enviroment:

> Unity3d 3.5.7 Nexus 5 4.4.2

It also can be reproduced on `KitKat emulator`.

**Note**: It works fine for all other devices < `Android 4.4`

Any help very appreciated.

Comment: same issue - http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/211847-Simulator-with-API-19-(KitKat)-always-crashes-in-onCreate

Comment: Strange thing that every app on Google Play done with Unity3D works on such device

Comment: Perhaps the issue is related to your version of Unity3d? 3.5.7 is fairly old now, the latest is 4.3. Maybe try updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the ART runtime? Unity3D does not work with ART yet, here are two links about that.

- Feedback posted in Unity3D to ask for support for ART here: http://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/add-support-for-art-runtime-on-android
- Also this forum post that talks a bit about Unity3D and ART, but there are no solutions: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/questions-about-android-4-4.215508/

If you are using Dalvik, then I don't know what it might be.

You can check if you're using Dalvik or ART in the **Developer options** in **Settings**. The option is called *"Select runtime"*.